# How to plot a phase portrait for this system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, matlab, mathematica

I beg your help.. I'd like the phase portrait for this system:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= x (7-x-2y) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &=  y (5-y-x)
\end{aligned}
I don't know how to use Mathematica/Matlab ... :(
If anyone can make this portrait and post a print screen here, I would thank you very much..

Comment: If you are brave enough to allow java applets, you can use http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~ashilnikov/software/newphase/newphase.html

Comment: I couldn't run.. Please, How can I enable?

Comment: You need to have Java with plugin installed and enabled in the browser. Some years ago this was the normal setup, but due to security holes, both are not so common today.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe how to make a phase portrait and someone here will help you implement it in Matlab or Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

The function you want in matlab is the [quiver](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) function.

The following will produce the required phase portrait, as I understand them.

```
% no domain is given, so I will use [-5,5] x [-5,5] 
%    with 50 subintervals in each direction
xdom = linspace(-5,5,51);
ydom = linspace(-5,5,51);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(xdom,ydom); % generate mesh of domain

U = X.*(7 - X - 2*Y); % dx/dt
V = Y.*(5 - X - Y);   % dy/dt

quiver(X,Y,U,V)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since $${dy\over dx}={{dy\over dt}\over {dx\over dt}}={y(5-y-x)\over x(7-x-2y)},\tag{$*$}$$ solution trajectories

- have slope zero (i.e., are horizontal) when $y=0$, $5-y-x=0\implies y=5-x$ (shown in red below),
- have undefined slope (i.e., are vertical) when $x=0$, $7-x-2y=0\implies y={7\over 2}-{1\over 2}x$ (shown in blue below).

If you want to proceed by hand, you could do a simple sign analysis based on the regions above/below each of those lines to determine the sign of the right-hand side of $(*)$ and hence the slope of trajectories.

Putting that information together, and letting *Mathematica* plot some trajectories, here's the phase portrait you get:

[image]

Comment: Nice-looking picture, but some of the arrows must be pointing in the wrong direction. For example, in the vicinity of the negative $y$ axis we have $dy/dt<0$, so all trajectories there should go downwards. There is also a similar strange discontinuous change in direction across the skew blue line.

Comment: $dy/dt<0$ means the $y$ coordinates of trajectories decrease, not that they have negative slope, which would be $dy/dx<0$. The picture bears this out.

Comment: Yes, decreasing $y$ coordinate is exactly what I meant by “go downwards”.  What I was trying to say is that the trajectories just to the left of the negative $y$ axis in the picture have *increasing* $y$ coordinate despite $dy/dt=y(5-y-x) \approx y(5-y)$ being *negative* in that region...

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here's a plot of the OP's vector field in the rectangle $[0, 8] \times [0, 6]$, scaled by $0.025$ so the arrows' lengths are visually meaningful. The red lines are $dx/dt = 0$; the blue lines are $dy/dt = 0$.

[image: Vector field plot]