# find the nullclines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to find the nullclines in the system (see picture attached) according to my professor (0,0) is one of them. I'm so confuse looking for it. [image]

Comment: No, (0,0) is not a nullcline, only a point on some nullcline (and actually on several nullclines). But (0,0) is a fixed point.

Comment: @Evangelina Just a friendly reminder in case you don’t know how the site works: after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "upvote" and/or "accept" the answer by clicking the up arrow and the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question and will encourage others to answer your other questions. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 5):

The nullclines (*null* meaning *zero*, *cline* meaning *slope*) of the system $$x'=f(x,y),\quad y'=g(x,y)$$ occur when $f(x,y)=0$ or $g(x,y)=0$. You have found these curves to be $$y=ax,\quad y={x\over b(1+x)}.$$

This means that for any point $P$ on the curve $y=ax$, that $x'\big|_P=0$. That is, on the curve $y=ax$, $x$ is not changing with respect to $t$.

Similarly, for any point $Q$ on the curve $y={x\over b(1+x)}$, that $y'\big|_Q=0$, so on the curve $y={x\over b(1+x)}$, $y$ is not changing with respect to $t$.

Finally, where these two curves intersect, namely, $$ax={x\over b(1+x)},$$ we get the points where neither $x$ not $y$ is changing with respect to $t$. These are called the *fixed points* of the system. Here, the fixed points occur at
$$x=0,\ y=0 \quad\text{and}\quad x={1-ab\over ab},\ y={1-ab\over b}.$$

As for sketching the phase portrait, take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/907335/52893) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/998554/52893).