# Plot phase plane for system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab

I'm in need of some help with matlab code.  I'm working on a problem which gives the following system:

$$x'=x^2 - x - y$$

$$y'=x-y$$

We are asked to solve the system numerically starting with $(x(0), y(0))=(-0.3,-0.3)$ for $t \in [0,10]$. Additionally, we are asked to plot the solution in a phase plane and also as a function of time.

My initial reaction is to try and use the **ode45** function, then plot the $x$ and $y$ components as functions of time.  The thing that I'm really having trouble with is plotting the phase plane...

Any help/links/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the phase plane and solution curve, are you using the stuff here http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/08/09/phase-portraits-of-a-system-of-odes/?

Comment: @Moo that was very helpful!  I wasn't aware of that site, but I'm glad/thankful you sent it my way.  Thank you very much--it did the trick for me.

Comment: Glad it was of service and that you resolved your issues! Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The phase portrait of a system of two first-order ODEs can be obtained in a similar manner as described in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/680852), e.g. using Matlab's `quiver` function. Otherwise, one can plot several trajectories $(x (t), y (t))$ obtained by numerical integration (here with `ode45`) and having different initial conditions.